# How do I sign in to GitHub from command line after password access is removed?

Tags: github

GitHub is retiring password based authentication for command line tools: https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/

Normally I work in some server, `git clone https://....`, enter my username and password and get the code that I have to deploy.

What am I supposed to do now? Do I create a token, write it down on a piece of paper, take it with me and retype it into a terminal? Seems a bit too convoluted for just getting some code. Is there some other "intended" workflow?

Comment: Well, then I have to somehow get a key on that machine. And remove it after I've cloned the code. At that point it's just easier to take a zip file with the code with me, isn't it?

Comment: Because I wouldn't want the owner of the server to access my github account

Comment: Got it, I see what you mean. (By the way this probably belongs on ServerFault.)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options:

- You can create a personal access token in your github settings and use that instead of your account password.
- you can use SSH to connect
- you can rely on the Git Credential Manager Core which will perform an OAuth check either by popping up a UI or giving you an url to paste into a browser.
- some hardware tokens will enable you to perform authentication.

Comment: Assume you've come to our premises to deploy a project on our server. You sit down in front of a linux shell. How do you proceed to get code from github?

Comment: You use any of the above options.

Comment: But you may need to come prepared and generate a PAT before you come there. Or you use your phone to generate one on the spot if that's permitted.